# Implementar la libreria halower/vue-tree en laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js

Estoy intentando usar la siguiente libreria https://github.com/halower/vue-tree/blob/master/README.md esta usa jsx, realiza todos los pasos de configuración pero me muestra error de renderización

Comment: Añade el error a la pregunta para que se entienda más